# How to bind @RequestParam to similar objectsin Spring?

Tags: spring, rest

I have simple POJO object with class:

```
public class Place
{
    @NotNull
    private String country;
    @NotNull
    private String city;
}
```

How to bind such objects to RequestParam as the here:

```
 public ResponseEntity find(@RequestParam String date, Place departure, Place arrival)
```

Use api :

> /find?date=2019-02-10T16:00:00&country=Russia&city=Samara&country=Russia&city=Moscow

get Response with use

```
System.out.println(departure);
System.out.println(arrival);
```

> Place{country='Russia,Russia', city='Samara,Moscow'}
>
> Place{country='Russia,Russia', city='Samara,Moscow'}

Can I get response as next:

> Place{country='Russia', city='Samara'}
>
> Place{country='Russia', city='Moscow'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Spring cannot differentiate your parameters with the same names, and stack them.
For such a small business object as a parameter, I would explicitly create a different name in a specific parameter object.

```
public void find(@RequestParam String date, Travel travel)
```

With an Object like this:

```
public class TravelDto {

  @NotNull
  private String fromCountry;
  @NotNull
  private String fromCity;
  @NotNull
  private String toCountry;
  @NotNull
  private String toCity;
....
}
```

For your situation it would makes things clear from the HTTP cal point of view:

> /find?date=2019-02-10T16:00:00&fromCountry=Russia&fromCity=Samara&toCountry=Russia&toCity=Moscow